# Laravel Polymoprhic Many to Many with one field updating

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, pivot-table

I have an `Equipment` model that is a Polymorphic Many-to-Many with a few other models.

Here is the issue I can't figure out. When an equipment is added to another model, the `hours` will change on the equipment each time. All other fields, sn, make, model are static. I want to set this up so I have a record of each of the changes to the hours field - so I can query the history.

Should I move hours to the `equipables` table? Add a pivot table? What is the best way to set this up?

Here is an overview of the migration for this model and the `Equipables` poly relation.

```
        Schema::create('equipment', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('sn')->index();
            $table->string('make');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->string('stock');
            $table->string('hours');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('equipables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer("equipment_id");
            $table->integer("equipable_id");
            $table->string("equipable_type");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this scenario by making and event and call it whenever any of your target models created or updated. By this way, you can track their behavior and update the equipment table.
For example, model *A* has a morph relationship with equipment, I make an event named `ACreated` by running `php artisan make:event ACreated` and call this event after creating an instance of A model.

```
$a = A::create([
    // Some sample array data here
]);

event(new ACreated($a));
```

ACreated event:

```
class ACreated
{
    public $a;

    public function __construct(App\Models\A $a){
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

Then in your **EventServiceProvider**, link *ACreated* event to an listener, for example *AWasCreated* listener(`php artisan make:listener AWasCreated`).

EventServiceProvider:

```
protected $listen = [
    App\Event\ACreated::class => [
        App\Listener\AWasCreated::class,
    ],
];
```

Finally, do your logic in the listener:

AWasCreated:

```
class AWasCreated
{
    public function handle($event){
        $a = $event->a;
        $a->equipment->increment('hours');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you Babak. But what is the best place to have the hours field? On the model itself won’t work as it’ll overwrite the old data. Is it best to have the hours field on the equipables table?

Comment: When you use morphByMany method, you have a morph table with a pivot table. You should define your custom columns in morph table not in pivot table. Pivot table should only store relationship data, but you can save extra data in there in special cases, not in your case.